# Unwinding back from a UITableViewCell push segue

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, segue

this is my first post here.
I am new to Xcode.
I have a Table View with a prototype cell that is connected with a push `segue` to another view.
I have an unwind `segue` in the table `view controller`, and created the segue in the second view by connection the `button` i want the action attached to to the green `exit button`.
The problem is that the unwind `segue` isn't called if the `segue` connecting the table view to the second view is a push `segue`, but it works if it is a modal segue which doesn't suit me because i need the nav bar.

Hope someone can help me.

here is the unwinding code:

```
- (IBAction)setApplied:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue 
{
    BriefsSelectViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];
    Brief *temp= source.b;
    temp.applied=YES;
    NSLog(@"hello"); 
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have attempted.

Comment: I think you want `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`.

Comment: You must be setting up something incorrectly. There's no reason it should work for a modal, but not a push. Did you connect the unwind segue to a button? Is the button active (does it dim when you touch it)? What result do you get; does nothing happen when you touch the button?

Comment: the unwind segue is connected to a button in the second view by ctrl-draggin from the button to greene exit button and selecting the unwind segue.
The button is active, it does dim when i press it but nothing happens when the segue connecting the table view to the second view is a push segue, but it does work when its a modal segue which is weird. @rdelmar

Comment: I've never seen a problem like this; it sounds like you're doing everything correctly. If you can post your project somewhere, I'll take a look at it and see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The way I managed to do it was adding the below code to the `second view` and linking `my button` to it.

```
- (IBAction)setApplied:(id)sender 
{
    b.applied=YES;
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}
```

I hope this helps someone who encounters the same issue.